# Pyomo Decrement by Decision Variable Values in Constraint Formula

Tags: python, pyomo

Below is an example Pyomo model that seeks to maximise the sum of bounded decision variables A, B for a set VALS 1, 2, 3 with the constraint that the sum cannot be greater than a defined maxNum parameter of 10000.

However, I would like to add an additional single decision variable, C that takes a defined parameter i.e. `startNum := 500` and is decremented by the sum of values assigned to A for each element in the set.

eg. given the following
A1 50
A2 35
A3 60

C = 355 (500 - (50 + 35 + 60))

I'm brand new to Pyomo and have no idea how to write the constraint function for C. I'd really appreciate some advice!

Many thanks...

A simple .dat file:

```
set VALS := 1 2 3;
param maxNum := 10000;
```

basic model formulation:

```
# define sets 
model.VALS = Set()

# parameters
model.maxNum = Param()

# decision variables
model.A = Var(model.WEEKS, within = NonNegativeIntegers, bounds = (0,100))
model.B = Var(model.WEEKS, within = NonNegativeIntegers, bounds = (100,200))

# constraints
def maxNum_rule(model):
    return sum(model.A[t]+model.B[t] for t in model.WEEKS) <= model.maxNum
model.maxNumCalc = Constraint(rule = maxNum_rule)

# objective function
def objective_rule(model):
    return sum(model.A[t] + model.B[t] for t in model.WEEKS)

model.maxNumObj = Objective(rule = objective_rule, sense = maximize)
```

Comment: What you have listed for `C` is just an expression in terms of `A`.  So, you don't need to create `C`.  Just make a constraint based on that expression.  Can you modify/edit your post to show what the intent of the expression is if that isn't clear?

Comment: Also, if you are just getting going, I'd strongly recommend you make concrete models instead of abstract.  Much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @AirSquid. I was tired and totally overthinking it. I've created `C` with a simple constraint based on `A`. Bit embarrassed it to have involved a Stack post in my sleep deprived thought process! Thank you for your time!